# Extract a dynamic value in a pattern to put it in another one

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have differents strings in the form of

```
Formula1(value) + Formula2(anotherValue) * 0.5
```

where `Formula1` and `Formula2` are *constants*. I would like to use *regex* to 
convert the initial string into

```
Formula1(value, constantWord) + Formula2(anotherValue, constantWord) * 0.5
```

Here `value`, `anotherValue` etc. are strings of *capital letters* and *numbers* and can be composed of `2` or `3` characters.

The regex for the `value`s is quite simple. But the rest part is more difficult for me.

How could I do that in **C#** or **Java**?

**Example:**

```
Swipe(YN1) + Avg(DNA) * 0.5
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
Swipe(YN1, calculated) + Avg(DNA, calculated) * 0.5
```

Comment: Could you provide some *examples*, please?

Comment: I add an exemple

Comment: I don't think it would work, "value" need to be a regex

Comment: I see that you want a *regex*, not `Replace` from the *example* provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *look ahead* and *look behind*

```
(?<=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*\(\s*)[A-Z0-9]{2,3}(?=\s*\))
```

**Regex details:**

We have simple *match* of interest `[A-Z0-9]{2,3}` - from `2` to `3` *capital letters* or *digits*. But this *match* should be *after* a formula (e.g. `Swipe(` or `Formula1(`) and *before* `)`. Assuming *formula* being an *identifier* (starts from letter, can contain letters or digits) we can put

```
(?<=  )      - group, behind: should appear before the match; will not be included into it
[A-Za-z]     - one letter (Formula1)
[A-Za-z0-9]* - letters or digits, zero or more
\s*          - whitespaces (spaces, tabultalions) - zero or more
```

Match

```
[A-Z0-9]{2,3} - Capital letters or digits from 2 to 3 characters
```

Finally we should look *ahead* in oreder to find out closing parenthesis:

```
(?= ) - group, ahead: should appear before the match; will not be included into it
\s*   - zero or more whitespaces (spaces, tabulations etc)      
\)   - closing parenthesis (escaped)
```

Combining, we have

```
(?<=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*\(\s*) -- Behind:
                                  --   Letter, zero or more letters or digits, parenthesis 

[A-Z0-9]{2,3}                     -- Value to match (2..3 capital letters or digits)

(?=\s*\)                          -- Ahead: 
                                  --   Closing parenthesis
```

Final pattern

```
(?<=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*\(\s*)[A-Z0-9]{2,3}(?=\s*\))
```

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for details

**C#** code:

```
string source = @"Swipe(YN1) + Avg(DNA) * 0.5";
string argument = "calculate";  

string result = Regex.Replace(
    source, 
  @"(?<=[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*\s*\(\s*)[A-Z0-9]{2,3}(?=\s*\))", 
    match => match.Value + $", {argument}");

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
Swipe(YN1, calculate) + Avg(DNA, calculate) * 0.5
```

Comment: This is working nicely, could you explain the regex ? Even with the doc i don't get it. Big thanks.